# 301 Redirect few pages of old domain to new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect only 3 urls to new domain using 301 redirect

```
example.com/about -> newdomain.com/about
example.com/test -> newdomain.com/test
```

any way to achieve this?
I have tried wordpress plugins but they allow relative domain redirect
like

```
newdomain.com/about -> newdomain.com/newabout
```

I think it can be done with .htaccess rule but I only found the rule to redirect entire site like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress   
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldsite.com RewriteRule (.*) 
http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
# END WordPress
```

I dont know how to modify this to meet my needs.

Comment: Have you tried changing the url in that rule to the url including the page part?

Comment: yes tried that but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?oldsite.com
RewriteRule ^/?(about|test)/?$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: added this `# BEGIN WordPress   
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?outsourcelocally.com
RewriteRule ^/?(about-us-2|contact|blog)/?$ http://www.olocally.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
# END WordPress` on top of .htaccess but not working

Comment: Works for me. Since you're using 301 redirects, make sure to CLEAR your browser cache since permanent redirects will be cached.

Comment: If you're using google chrome, you can press ctrl+shift+j to open the developer tools. Then click the "network" tab and check the "disable cache" checkbox. Then try your request again. Any time the developer tools is open in the future, it will disable browser cache for the duration of the page request.

Comment: and I am supposed to add this rule to the old domain server?

Comment: Yes, put that code in an `.htaccess` file located at the web root, usually public_html, on your old domain. That way anyone requesting a file on your old domain will get a chance for the .htaccess logic to be processed and be redirected to your new domain.